# Simple java application that can send messages to ActiveMQ broker

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, activemq-classic

I'm going to write a simple Java (console) app which sends some messages to ActiveMQ broker.

- Do I have to use Java EE for this? Can I use Java SE instead?
- If I have to use Java EE, which type of app should I choose?

Comment: You can use ActiveMQ with Java SE. The [download](http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-560-release.html) comes with the standalone ready to use.

Comment: Does that include javax.jms.* stuffs?

Answer (score 3):

The `javax.jms package` from `Java EE` with the [`Active MQ libraries`](http://activemq.apache.org/) are enough to implement the functionality you want to have.

Here is [the link to an example application](http://www.javablogging.com/simple-guide-to-java-message-service-jms-using-activemq/)

The Java EE SDK can be downloaded [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html), you only need the Java EE SDK ("Java EE SDK 6" or "Java EE SDK 6 + JDK 7", at your choice). Neither `Glassfish Application Server` nor `WebProfile` are required for this task.